# Use deferred to make an infinite call loop

Tags: twisted, deferred

Can we use deferred (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html) to make an infinite call loop in which a function adds itself to a deferred chain? I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
d = deferred.Deferred()
first = True

def loopPrinting(dump):
  ch = chr(random.randint(97, 122))
  print ch
  global d, first
  d.addCallback(loopPrinting)
  if first:
    d.callback('a')
    first = False
  return d

loopPrinting('a')

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a good use for Deferreds.  Instead, try using `reactor.callLater`:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

def loopPrinting():
    print chr(random.randint(97, 122))
    reactor.callLater(1.0, loopPrinting)

loopPrinting()
reactor.run()
```

Or `twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall`:

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

def loopPrinting():
    print chr(random.randint(97, 122))

loop = task.LoopingCall(loopPrinting)
loop.start(1.0)
reactor.run()
```

Your Deferred-based version has a couple problems.  First, it defines a callback on a Deferred that returns *the same Deferred*.  Returning a Deferred (let's call it `a`) from a callback on another Deferred (let's call it `b`) does something called "chaining".  It makes `b` pause its callback chain until `a` has a result.  In the case where `a` and `b` are actually the same Deferred instance, this makes little or no sense.

Second, when adding a callback to a Deferred that already has a result, the callback will be called immediately.  In your case, your callback adds another callback.  And that callback adds another callback.  So you have an infinite loop all contained inside your `d.addCallback(loopPrinting)` line.  This will prevent the reactor from ever running, breaking any other part of your program.

Comment: I was trying to avoid callLater in my code, or other method that time-based. I'm trying to make a chain of functions in which one will be executed after the previous is done, so the running of the chain will be independent from time. Does there exist a way to do that ?